# Extending an Annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I've got a couple of annotations, which share a common method

String code();

Now, in some generic code, I would like to have something like a common base annotation, that has the same common method. I am thinking about something like

```
public @interface BaseAnnotation {
    String code();
}

public @interface MyAnnotation extends BaseAnnotation {
}
```

so, that my generic code might include

```
BaseAnnotation ba = (BaseAnnotation) annotation;
String code = ba.code();
```

Is something like that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Yes but you need to use a plain interface for the parent. An annotation can't extend another annotation.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: So, that I would have

    public @ interface MyAnnotation extends BaseAnnotationInterface {
    }